# Resource temporarily unavailable for glutInit function

Tags: c, gcc, freeglut

Test code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    perror("err");

    return 0;
}

I compile the program as follows:
```

gcc test.c -lglut -lGL -lGLEW -lGLU -lm -o test

```
I got the following error when the program was running.
```

err: Resource temporarily unavailable

```
Why did this happen?
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the documentation of `glutInit` that it is setting `errno`.

Comment: in other words, looking at errno is meaningless. gutInit reports no errors according to the docs. In fact it will terminate the program "During this process, glutInit may cause the termination of the GLUT program with an error message to the user if GLUT cannot be properly initialized"